# Starting Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, html-agility-pack

So I am trying to learn how to write asynchronous methods and have been banging my head to get asynchronous calls to work.  What always seems to happen is the code hangs on "await" instruction until it eventually seems to time out and crash the loading form in the same method with it.

There are two main reason this is strange:

1. The code works flawlessly when not asynchronous and just a simple loop
2. I copied the MSDN code almost verbatim to convert the code to asynchronous calls here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674889.aspx

I know there are a lot of questions already about this on the forms but I have gone through most of them and tried a lot of other ways (with the same result) and now seem to think something is fundamentally wrong after MSDN code wasn't working.

Here is the main method that is called by a background worker:

```
// this method loads data from each individual webPage
async Task LoadSymbolData(DoWorkEventArgs _e)
{
    int MAX_THREADS = 10;
    int tskCntrTtl = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    Dictionary<string, string> newData_d = new Dictionary<string, string>(tskCntrTtl);
    // we need to make copies of things that can change in a different thread
    List<string> links = new List<string>(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(r => r.Cells[dbIndexs_s.url].Value.ToString()).ToList());
    List<string> symbols = new List<string>(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(r => r.Cells[dbIndexs_s.symbol].Value.ToString()).ToList());
    // we need to create a cancelation token once this is working
    // TODO

    using (LoadScreen loadScreen = new LoadScreen("Querying stock servers..."))
    {
        // we cant use the delegate becaus of async keywords
        this.loaderScreens.Add(loadScreen);
        // wait until the form is loaded so we dont get exceptions when writing to controls on that form
        while ( !loadScreen.IsLoaded() );
        // load the total number of operations so we can simplify incrementing the progress bar
        // on seperate form instances
        loadScreen.LoadProgressCntr(0, tskCntrTtl);
        // try to run all async tasks since they are non-blocking threaded operations
        for (int i = 0; i < tskCntrTtl; i += MAX_THREADS)
        {
            List<Task<string[]>> ProcessURL = new List<Task<string[]>>();
            List<int> taskList = new List<int>();

            // Make a list of task indexs
            for (int task = i; task < i + MAX_THREADS && task < tskCntrTtl; task++)
                taskList.Add(task);

            // ***Create a query that, when executed, returns a collection of tasks.
            IEnumerable<Task<string[]>> downloadTasksQuery =
                from task in taskList select QueryHtml(loadScreen, links[task], symbols[task]);

            // ***Use ToList to execute the query and start the tasks. 
            List<Task<string[]>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

            // ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain.
            while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                // Identify the first task that completes.
                Task<string[]> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);   // <---- CODE HANGS HERE

                // ***Remove the selected task from the list so that you don't
                // process it more than once.
                downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

                // Await the completed task.
                string[] data = await firstFinishedTask;
                if (!newData_d.ContainsKey(data.First())) 
                    newData_d.Add(data.First(), data.Last());
            }
        }
        // now we have the dictionary with all the information gathered from teh websites
        // now we can add the columns if they dont already exist and load the information
        // TODO
        loadScreen.UpdateProgress(100);
        this.loaderScreens.Remove(loadScreen);
    }
}
```

And here is the async method for querying web pages:

```
async Task<string[]> QueryHtml(LoadScreen _loadScreen, string _link, string _symbol) 
{
    string data = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var html = await client.GetStringAsync(_link);    // <---- CODE HANGS HERE
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        string percGrn = doc.FindInnerHtml(
            "//span[contains(@class,'time_rtq_content') and contains(@class,'up_g')]//span[2]");
        string percRed = doc.FindInnerHtml(
            "//span[contains(@class,'time_rtq_content') and contains(@class,'down_r')]//span[2]");

        // create somthing we'll nuderstand later
        if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(percRed)) ||
            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(percRed)))
            throw new Exception();

        // adding string to empty gives string
        string perc = percGrn + percRed;
        bool isNegative = String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn);
        double percDouble;

        if (double.TryParse(Regex.Match(perc, @"\d+([.])?(\d+)?").Value, out percDouble))
            data = (isNegative ? 0 - percDouble : percDouble).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        // update the progress bar...
        _loadScreen.IncProgressCntr();
    }

    return new string[] { _symbol, data };
}
```

I could really use some help.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you wrap that into a `BackgroundWorker`? It's already asynchronous as soon as you await the call of `LoadSymbolData`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the background worker runs on a separate thread which is different than just being asynchronous.

Comment: A `BackgroundWorker` does its work on another thread, yes. You may want to do that, if the UI-thread shouldn't be blocked as this would cause a freeze of your UI-components.
`async`-`await` adds a new way of executing code asynchronously, so that the application **won't** be blocked. As soon as you await your `Task`, it will run asynchronously (if it also awaits another method internally or runs a new `Task`). There is no need for another thread.

Comment: My background routine in abstraction is an asynchronous routine ran on a separate thread from the main UI so that the UI can handle intensive processing events without bottle necking asynchronous awaited events.  So I split it up on two separate threads so that I can receive data faster and eliminate some latency from the main UI.  Keep in mind I have already tested and confirmed there's a difference in this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short when you combine async with any 'regular'  task functions you get a deadlock

http://olitee.com/2015/01/c-async-await-common-deadlock-scenario/

the solution is by using configureawait

```
var html = await client.GetStringAsync(_link).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The reason you need this is because you didn't await your orginal thread.

```
// ***Create a query that, when executed, returns a collection of tasks.
IEnumerable<Task<string[]>> downloadTasksQuery = from task in taskList select QueryHtml(loadScreen,links[task], symbols[task]);
```

What's happeneing here is that you mix the await paradigm with thre regular task handling paradigm. and those don't mix (or rather you have to use the ConfigureAwait(false) for this to work.

Comment: I am still pretty new at this so I will have to do some research as to exactly what you mean.  I had to ConfigureAwait(false) to both what you had mentioned and also Task<string[]> firstFinishedTask = 
                            await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks)

Comment: For some reason though my LoadScreen disappears after a certain amount of time.  It was complaining about cross thread communication with it (even though it has invokes in most of its methods) so I went ahead and pulled it out of the QueryHtml() method and just called it from LoadSymbolData() after the number of threads MAX_THREADS is complete.  But it still disappears... after stepping through it seems to still be going through the methods and having all for the right information.  It seems to step over the invoke sections though...