# Immediately process asynchronous results in the order they were requested

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Suppose I kick off 5 async tasks, and I want to print the results in the order they were requested:

```
public async void RunTasks()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoSomething(i));
    }

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', results));
}

public async Task<int> DoSomething(int taskNumber)

{
    var random = new Random();
    await Task.Delay(random.Next(5000));
    return taskNumber;
}
```

This will always print "1,2,3,4,5" - because Task.WhenAll() orders the results by the order **requested**, not by the order in which they finished.

Unfortunately this means I have to wait for ALL Tasks to finish until I can print anything.

How might I instead print the result of each task as soon as it's finished, but still respecting the order they were requested?

So I should always see "1,2,3,4,5" - but it may arrive gradually:

```
"1"
"1,2,3"
"1,2,3,4"
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

(no need to worry about the actual reasoning for doing this, treat it as a fun problem)

Comment: This looks a lot like [Starting Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37398050/215552) but that question is a mess. The answer might help though :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(DoSomething(i));
}

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    var result = await task;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

We kick off all of the tasks first, then loop over them in order, awaiting each in turn. If the task being awaited has previously completed, the await just returns its result. Otherwise we wait until it completes.

Answer (score 2):

Try a [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2?view=netcore-2.2) it will output the items it processes one by one in the order the were received by default even if the elements are processed in parallel.

```
public async Task Order()
{
    var tBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string>(async x =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return x.ToString();
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 });
    var sub = tBlock.AsObservable().Subscribe(x => Console.Write(x));

    foreach (var num in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        tBlock.Post(num);
    }
    tBlock.Complete();
    await tBlock.Completion;
    sub.Dispose();
}
```

Output:

```
0123456789
```